# django server replies synchronously to multiple ajax get requests

Tags: ajax, django, heroku

I have a web page who sends multiple ajax get request to a django server.
The server does some internet crawling for each request it gets and returns a response to the client once it finishes.
It seems that the server replies to the requests one after another.
I'm considering to send each request to a Celery worker to make the server's responses asynchronous but I'm not sure if it will solve the problem.

Also I'm using django on heroku and not sure how to combine celery with django on heroku.

Comment: you don't need Celery, you just need to have more than one Django process running on the dyno... what web server are you using?  supply more details about your serving config

Comment: I would like the server to act as if there is a thread per request..  I am using the default settings as shown at the getting started with django on heroku tutorial

Comment: if you talk about threads in the context of Python concurrency then you need to be aware of the limitations of the GIL https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Thanks for the reference.
Do you suggest that there is an inherent bottle-neck that prevents the server from serving requests concurrently? there has to be a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heroku Django tutorial app uses gunicorn as the server, as you can see here:
https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/Procfile

There is no special gunicorn config in the tutorial app, so you are running with gunicorn default settings. You can see what they are here:
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes

You'll note that this means you have a single worker process, of the `sync` type (i.e. no [greenlets](https://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) magic to enable concurrency within the single Python process)

It does say you can scale gunicorn to use multiple processes (still on a single Heroku dyno) by setting the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable, on Heroku this is easily done from your local shell using the cli tools:

```
$ heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=4
```

Gunicorn docs suggest setting this to "A positive integer generally in the `2-4 x $(NUM_CORES)` range."  Your basic Heroku dyno will be a single core.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to set it to maximal performance ?

Comment: "maximal performance" very much depends on detail of your app, but to get the most capacity out of your dyno you'll need to look into the greenlets thing... I recommend [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). There is not much shortcut to getting the best out of it: have to read, learn, fine tune config in context of real load. Some [people](http://blog.kgriffs.com/2012/12/18/uwsgi-vs-gunicorn-vs-node-benchmarks.html) also [recommend](http://cramer.io/2013/06/27/serving-python-web-applications/) using [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) over gunicorn.